# some files from github repo are not being pulled

Tags: git, github

I have tried to synchronize my local machine with a remote Github repo and everything went ok, except some (not all) new folders have not been pulled and if I now try to pull again, I get the message saying that my local is already up to date.

I have used command

```
git pull origin master
```

When I go to my VS Code editor and point to the changes in that repo, it also shows that my local and remote are synchronized, which clearly is not the case (at least from my perspective, since I am missing some folders on my local that are present on remote).

I didn't find anything mentioning something like this. Anyone knows where the error may be, or at least where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you're describing is, quite simply, not possible. That's good news. It means you're merely missing something.

1. Are the folders empty? Git tracks *files*, so if you have an empty folder, it doesn't exist as far as git is concerned.

   You will often see people use a hidden file like `.keep` inside of a folder that they want to ensure is committed to the repo but doesn't have any other files. You can create one (on *nix/mac) by running `touch your_folder/.keep`.
2. If there are files in the folders, are they committed to the repository? Running `git status` can help you find out, but isn't always going to show. They could be ignored by git due to settings. The easiest way to check: `git ls-files` will list all of the files git is tracking.

   You can also list ignored files along with the source of the ignore rule with `git check-ignore -v *` (mac/unix only I believe), which should help you track down the source of the confusion.
3. Does your remote repository have the same branch checked out as your local copy? Running `git branch` will show you the current branch if you don't have your shell configured to show this in the prompt.

Comment: No it is my repo and those folders contain React apps. I am working on several computers and want to synchronize my laptop with that repo.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have resolved it. The problem was that, for whatever reason, my VS Code didn't update itself with the new folders (only some of them which is strange), but those folders were actually pulled.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to verify that your remote branch is "master".
It could be that you might have pushed code into a different branch in remote and trying to pull it from master.

```
git pull origin "branch-name"
```

Comment: No there is only one branch, and I have successfully pulled other folders from it, just two of them are not being pulled.

Comment: git fetch origin master ; 
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD